# Openssl ERR_error_string error description returns null

Tags: c, openssl

Trying to print OpenSSL error descriptions:

```
for (unsigned long int  er_code=0;er_code<100;er_code++)
{
char * err_data;
ERR_error_string(er_code, err_data);
printf("error code: %lu data: %s\n", er_code, err_data); 
}
```

Got all null's. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`err_data` is an unitialized pointer. According to [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ERR_error_string.html), "*buf* must be at least 256 bytes long."

So try:

```
for (unsigned long int er_code = 0; er_code < 100; er_code++)
{
    char err_data[256];
    ERR_error_string(er_code, err_data);
    printf("error code: %lu data: %s\n", er_code, err_data);
}
```

Or, "If *buf* is NULL, the error string is placed in a static buffer." So you could also do:

```
for (unsigned long int er_code = 0; er_code < 100; er_code++)
{
    char* err_data = ERR_error_string(er_code, NULL);
    printf("error code: %lu data: %s\n", er_code, err_data);
}
```